# ios version of themes and styles

Tags: android, ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

As an Android developer new to iOS/swift, I am trying to implement a global theme/style which every view controller can inherit. I expect one file which I can modify which would affect all View Controllers's UI. This is possible in android. Does iOS have anything similar?

Comment: no It doesn't have style/theme in ios application

Comment: you better try react-native for less code.

Answer (score -1):

The best match for what you are looking for is probably UIAppearance, although not quite the same.

What it allows you to do is basically setup each component once, and then have that be the default look for all other components.

An example for setting button colors (you could do this in your AppDelegate):

```
UIButton.appearance().setTitleColor(.white, forState: .normal)
UIButton.appearance().backgroundColor = .blue
```

Try looking at these tutorials:

https://www.raywenderlich.com/108766/uiappearance-tutorial

http://blog.iseinc.biz/use-uiappearance-create-ios-app-themes

Answer (score -2):

Usually if you want to do something like that, you can go to the AppDelegate File, and add code like the ones below:

```
[[UITextField appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTranslucent:NO];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

For example textfield by default has a bluish tint color, but with the code above, the default tint color becomes red. The single line of code you place will affect all UI related to it. Try it out.